# Consume JSON from a URL in Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

The question is: How can I import json from a URL specifically, NOT an internal file in Express, and contain it such that I can use it across multiple views. For example, I have a controller. How can I get in in there (controller)? I am using `request`.

I have a router with 2 routes but I want to have a bunch more, and the bulk of the logic for the routes is being done in controllers.

Below is a controller with the route for showing all. I had hardcoded a small piece of "json" in it as data to use temporarily, but now I want to populate my view via an outside api. This is my controller:

```
module.exports = {

//show all USERS
showDogs: (req,res) => {
const dogs = [
  {
    name:"Fluffy", breed:"ChowChow", slug:"fluffy", description:"4 year old Chow. Really, really fluffy."
  },
  {
    name:"Buddy", breed:"White Lab", slug:"buddy", description:"A friendly 6 year old white lab mix. Loves playing ball"
 },
 {
  name: "Derbis", breed:"Schmerbis",slug:"derbis", description:"A real Schmerbis Derbis"
 }
 ];
  res.render("pages/dogs", {dogs: dogs, title:"All Dogs"});
  }
};
```

How can I get this json the data to come from an outside line? I have used `request` before but I don't know how to transfer the data between files. I don't want to put it inside the `showDogs` or it won't be accessible to other functions here. Right?
I had something like this below, with `require('request')` at the top of the controller, but it just gave errors.

```
 const options = {

 url:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matteocrippa/dogbreedjsondatabase/master/dog-breed.json',
  method:'GET',
  headers:{
    'Accept-Charset': "utf-8"
NO IDEA ABOUT THIS AREA FOR NOW EITHER
  }
```

I also tried wrapping the entire thing, all the functions, in a request:

```
request('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matteocrippa/dogbreedjsondatabase/master/dog-breed.json', function(error, response, body)
```

But still I got an error.

And this the route.js where the controller sends:

```
   //dogs
   router.get('/dogs', dogsController.showDogs)
```

I am a Node beginner so the only thought I have is to write some middleware. The deeper problem here is I don't know how to use/write middleware properly. Perhaps I can become informed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a utility file that contains the code to talk to the external API. Include this file and use it's function to get dogs data. Later, you can add more functions for other APIs as well.

```
   const getDogData = require('../externalApis').getDogData;

   module.exports = {

       //show all USERS
       showDogs: (req, res) => {
           getDogData(function(err, dogs) {
                   if (err) {
                       //handle err
                   } else {

                       res.render("pages/dogs", {
                           dogs: dogs,
                           title: "All Dogs"
                       });
                   }
               }

           }
       };




       // externalApis.js
       const request = require ('request');

       module.exports = {
           getDogData: function(done) {

               const options = {
                   url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matteocrippa/dogbreedjsondatabase/master/dog-breed.json',
                   method: 'GET',
                   headers: {
                       'Accept-Charset': "utf-8"
                   }
               }

               request(options, function(error, response, body) {
                   if (error) {
                       return done(err);
                   } else {

                       var data = JSON.parse(body); // not sure how's data is returned or if it needs JSON.parse
                       return done(null, data.dogs); //return dogs
                   }

               });

           }
```